# Criar classes e ids aleatórios

Tags: html, random

Como crio classes e ids aleatórios no HTML?

Uma plataforma aqui com quem eu trabalho, ela, toda atualização de página, uma dív no Footer atualiza suas classes e ids, dum modo randômico.

Por exemplo, agora ela está assim:

```
<div id="wenro66zls" class="cwenro66zls"></div>
```

Eu atualizei a página, e ela ficou assim (OBS, mesma div):

```
  <div id="ldj38hec0v" class="cldj38hec0v"></div>
```

É tipo uma geração de senha, não sei...

Isso é feito com JavaScript? É algo simples?

Comment: Isso tem cara de automatizador de tarefas, podes pegar como exemplo Gulp e Grunt, são usados para concatenar, minificar códigos e outras tarefas necessárias para um bom código

Comment: Saberia dizer qual é o objetivo desta plataforma fazer isso?

Comment: @FelipeDuarte mas isso ocorre na build, não quando se atualiza a página.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é o logo deles no rodapé, o pessoal tava ponto display none, ai agora não da mais.

Comment: @Renan, realmente, enfim, isso ai é um mistério para mim

Comment: Tem cara de ser server-side. Quanto à geração, é algo bem simples de se fazer.

Comment: Caso queiram ver, podem ver aqui: http://www.pampili.com.br/ o logo la em baixo no rodapé, da BizCommerce.

Comment: Considerando que a plataforma é Magento, acredito que a geração deste código é feito ainda no PHP ao gerar o HTML entregue ao navegador, justamente para, como você disse, buscar evitar que o elemento seja oculto através de CSS e JS. Inclusive um pouco antes do elemento há um código JS que verifica se o elemento foi ocultado, se entendi bem.

Comment: Mas no caso seria com PHP, certo? Como poderia criar essas classes e IDs aleatorias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tu olhar o javascript que tem logo acima dessa, logo tu vai ver que teu um trecho no código assim:

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
plat_id = letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)) + (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substr(2, 9);
```

Esse é o código que gera a classe aleatória.

Segue abaixo a explicação do código.

```js
var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var plat_id = letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)) + (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substr(2, 9);

/* * Passo a passo * */

// === Primeira letra ===
// gera um número aleatório entre 0 e o tamanho de `letters`
var passo_1 = Math.random() * letters.length;

// arredonda para baixo
var passo_2 = Math.floor(passo_1);

// retorna a letra no índice randômico gerado acima
var passo_3 = letters.charAt(passo_2)

// => O código acima apenas escolhe uma letra aleatório da string `letters`

// === Restante da string ===
// gera um número aleatório entre 1 e 2
var passo_4 = Math.random() + 1;
// representação do número na base 36
var passo_5 = passo_4.toString(36);
// pega 9 caracteres começando do 3º
var passo_6 = passo_5.substr(2, 9);

// === Resultado ===
// Concatena a letra randômica inicial com a string gerada na 2ª parte
var passo_7 = passo_3 + passo_6;

console.log("passo_1: ", passo_1);
console.log("passo_2: ", passo_2);
console.log("passo_3 (letra inicial): ", passo_3);
console.log("passo_4: ", passo_4);
console.log("passo_5: ", passo_5);
console.log("passo_6 (restante da string): ", passo_6);
console.log("passo_7 (resultado): ", passo_7);
```

Comment: Show, Fernando! Logo más dou as 50+ pra ti, quando liberar!

Comment: Tranquilo, sempre fico curioso quando tem que mexer no código dos outros.  :)

Comment: Sem contar que os +50 vão automaticamente para a resposta aceita pelo autor...